# How to set the image name in gridview and use the image name in the database android

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-viewholder

I'm having a hard time to figure out on what am I going to do with my code please help.

I already got the answer on how will the user set a name for the image in gridview the problem is, it constantly changes every time I click it and input new data. After adding a name and description of the image, the next click of the user the image must do other activity like viewing its content.

How will I set it as the official name of the image and use the name as a reference in the database? The name or the id of the image will be used in adding different information. How will I do it? Should I use ViewHolder? Please help?

Here is my code:

```
    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {       
        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        View gridV;

        gridV = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_content, null);
        holder.img=(ImageView) gridV.findViewById(R.id.homeImage);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageID[position]);

         gridV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {        
                    showCustomDialog(position);
            }
        });

        return gridV;
    }

    protected void showCustomDialog(final int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Holder holder=new Holder();
        holder.tv=(TextView) gridV.findViewById(R.id.homeText);

//      if (homeText[position] == null)
//      {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Grid.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_land);

        final EditText lname = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.land_name);
        final EditText ldesc = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.land_description);

        Button ok_button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);    
        ok_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String land_name = lname.getText().toString();
                String land_desc = ldesc.getText().toString();
                //Get the text view and set its value

                if (land_name.matches(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You did not enter a name!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else
                {
                mydb.insertLand(land_name, land_desc);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), land_name+" Land Added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                homeText[position] = land_name;
                holder.tv.setText(homeText[position]);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), homeText[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't get it, what are you trying to do? What you want to do on the click of grid item?

Comment: Irrespective of what you want to do when user clicks the ListView item you will have to add a `OnItemClickListener` to it.

Comment: After adding the name of the image, the user should be able to view  the contents of the image and store the image name in the database.

Comment: So here you have to different action. I would suggest you to focus on one first. Start with saving the image name into database. Go through this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html and try to implement it. If you face any problem surely someone will help you.

Comment: I already save it on the database Sir. I got it correctly, the problem I face here is that every time I click on the image it shows the dialog box again that tend to change the existing name of the image. I want to set the image name exclusive for one image and don't overwrite the name. I'll just figure out the answer on my own Sir. Thank you for your time Sir and I'm sorry if I can't explain my problem correctly. I really appreciate your effort Sir. Thank you very much :D